# How to add hyperlink on array values in a table?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm wanna to add hyperlink on every emails and phone numbers that appear in the table like shown below

[image]

This is the code that I'm writing right now.

```
<tbody>
            <?php
                $grand_total_amount = 0;

                foreach ($processed_sales as $key => $sale):
            ?> 
                <tr class="sale" data-id="<?= $sale['id']; ?>">
                    <td><?= $pagination->offset + $key + 1; ?></td>
                <?php
                    foreach ($columns as $key => $value):
                        if ($checked_columns[$key]):
                ?>
                    <td><?= $sale[$key]; ?>
                    <a href="../Jualan.php?email=<?php echo $value['email']; ?>" class="style1"><?php echo $value['email']; ?></a></td>
                <?php
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                ?>
                </tr>
            <?php
                    $grand_total_amount = bcadd($grand_total_amount, $sale['total_amount'], 2);
                endforeach;
            ?>
            </tbody>
```

I only want the data in column email and phone number to have hyperlink that will direct them to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you're doing but what I could figure out is, your `<a>` tags should be within `<td>` tags, like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="../Jualan.php?email=<?php echo $value['email']; ?>" class="style1">
        <?php echo $value['email']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Otherwise it would messup the table.

Comment: ohhhh yeah my mistake. It's like this, if you see in the image that i have linked, thats how my table looks like right now. What i wanted to do is to make the values in column email and phone number can be click in meaning having a hyperlink on them

Comment: Just wrap the email and phone number values around ‘<a>’ tags and then wrap the ‘<a>’ tags with ‘<td>‘ tags, just like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your  should be inside your  maybe that's why it doesnt works

```
 echo "<a href=\"./$value['email']/">$value['email'];</a>";
```

Comment: Please add some details why this answers OPs question. Thank you.